# The Content already has an existing parent when use Comparator to sort

Tags: java, comparator, jdom-2

I use jdom2 to get a Element list from xml string. 
and want to sort it by getChildText.

This is my Comparator:

```
public class ComparatorFunc implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object arg0, Object arg1) {
        Element e1 = (Element) arg0;
        Element e2 = (Element) arg1;

        int flag = e1.getChildText("EntType").compareTo(e2.getChildText("EntType"));
        return flag;
    }
}
```

This is my code:

```
String xmlStr = request.getParameter("xmlStr");
xmlStr = xmlStr.trim();
//System.out.println(xmlStr);

ByteArrayInputStream xmlStream = null;

try {
    xmlStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlStr.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    if (xmlStream != null) {
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder(false);
        org.jdom2.Document document = builder.build(xmlStream);

        Element root = document.getRootElement();

        List<Element> listItem = root.getChildren("item");
        ComparatorFunc comparator = new ComparatorFunc();
        Collections.sort(listItem, comparator);

        .....
```

But I get this error:

```
org.jdom2.IllegalAddException: The Content already has an existing parent "design"
```

so how can i do?

Comment: Where do you get that exception? Does creating a new List before sorting help?

Comment: @qqilihq at this line `Collections.sort(listItem, comparator);`

Comment: Then try creating a copy of the List before.

Answer (score 0):

JDOM requires that content is always valid. This includes the intermediate results during a sort process.

The native sort method from Java swaps content by first 'setting' it in the new place before it 'removes' it from the old place, creating a duplicate.

This is a known problem.

The solution is to use the [sort method on the Element](http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html#sortChildren%28java.util.Comparator%29) which does things 'right'.

You can also sortContent(), or sortAttributes() if you want.

As a side note, consider the following for your input:

```
org.jdom2.Document document = builder.build(new StringReader(xmlStr));
```